# How to deploy a Kubernetes service using NodePort on AWS?

Tags: docker, amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have created a cluster on AWS EC2 using `kops` consisting of a master node and two worker nodes, all with public IPv4 assigned.

Now, I want to create a deployment with a service using NodePort to expose the application to the public.

After having created the service, I retrieve the following information, showing that it correctly identified my three pods:

```
nlykkei:~/projects/k8s-examples$ kubectl describe svc hello-svc
Name:                     hello-svc
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=hello
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"hello"},"name":"hello-svc","namespace":"default"},"spec"...
Selector:                 app=hello-world
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       100.69.62.27
Port:                     <unset>  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30001/TCP
Endpoints:                100.96.1.5:8080,100.96.2.3:8080,100.96.2.4:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

However, when I try to visit any of my public IPv4's on port 30001, I get no response from the server. I have already created a Security Group allowing all ingress traffic to port 30001 for all of the instances.

Everything works with Docker Desktop for Mac, and here I notice the following service field not present in the output above:

```
LoadBalancer Ingress:     localhost
```

I've already studied https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/, and think that NodePort should serve my needs?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you ssh to your ec2 and do curl on port 30001 from there, does it work?

Answer (score 1):

More often than not you should not be using NodePort.

You're in AWS so you can consume the [AWS Cloud Provider](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/#aws). Try using `ingress` resources or `LoadBalancer` service types. NLBs can do TCP/UDP port passthrough if that's what you need.

**Edit:** After further review, it looks like your just exposing a web server (I noted port `8080`). `NodePort` is 100% not what you want. Look at [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)